# How to run PHP 7 from command line...?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7

PHP 7 is installed.  Have a test script in php.  Trying to launch from command line.

```
[root@/php]# vim db_connect.php
[root@/php]# php db_connect.php
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install php5-cli

[root@/php]# php7 db_connect.php
No command 'php7' found, did you mean:

[root@/php]# php-7 db_connect.php
php-7: command not found

[root@/php]# php -v
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install php5-cli

[root@/php]# apt-get install php7-cli
E: Unable to locate package php7-cli
```

What is the command to launch with php7?

Comment: `apt-get install php5-cli` certainly will not install php7.

Comment: See: [How to install PHP 7? on askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7)

Comment: Once your up and running I would recommend using PDO commands instead of db_connect. It has security issues which you can find out about on this site under that term.

Comment: PHP 7 is already installed guys.... that's the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing php7.0-cli fixed it.

```
apt-get install php7.0-cli

[root@/php]# php -v
PHP 7.0.5-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group

[root@/php]# php db_connect.php
test
PDO connection object created
```

Comment: How to install last version of PHP?